# How to reverse SKTransition?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktransition

I have a button, that when pressed, moves to the next scene with the "doorway" transition. The doorway transition has no counterpart and opens differently when coming back. Is it possible for me to create a inverted doorway transition?

Comment: Add some code that you tried so that anyone can find the issue in that and provide the solution.

Comment: There is no reverse transition feature as I know (at the time of speaking). But making something similar by yourself would be an easy task... Just take a screenshot and scale fade rotate it or whatevet

Comment: @Whirlwind How might I do this for this specific transition?

Comment: As I said, you can do it from scratch by yourself. You can't modify existing transitions to work that way.